# Updating stock amount in another database table with user input

Tags: java, mysql

I have an order table in my database which a staff member could use to input a new order into, which is linked to an inventory table that retains the stockAmount for the products in my product table. I can get the orders being added to my order table but i can't get the stockAmount to update. This is my method so far.

```
@FXML
    public void AddOrder(ActionEvent event) {


        String orderID= orderBox.getText();
        String customerID = customerBox.getText();
        String productID = productBox.getText();
        String amount = amountBox.getText();
        String cost = costBox.getText();
        String date = dateBox.getText();





        dc = new Database();



        try {
         c = dc.Connect();
        query = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ordertable (orderID,customerID,productID,Amount,Cost, Date)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        update=c.prepareStatement ("UPDATE inventory set stockAmount ="+amount+" WHERE productID ="+productID+"");
        query.setString(1, orderID);
        query.setString(2, customerID);
        query.setString(3, productID);
        query.setString(4, amount);
        query.setString(5, cost);
        query.setString(6, date);
        query.executeUpdate();
        update.executeUpdate();
        Alert confirmation = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Saved");
        // closeConfirmation.showMessageDialog(this, "Saved");
        confirmation.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    orderBox.clear();
    customerBox.clear();
    productBox.clear();
    amountBox.clear();
    costBox.clear();
    dateBox.clear();

}
```

The error i'm getting (2AAB is the productID i'm inputting, and it exists under the productID column in my inventory table)

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '2AAB' in 'where clause'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2501)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at application.OrderController.AddOrder(OrderController.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a prepared statement for the `UPDATE`?

Comment: The problem is that you didn't put the product ID in quotes. But if you used a prepared statement you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: I have 

 private PreparedStatement query;
private PreparedStatement update;

As variables. I take it that this isn't enough?

Comment: The problem is that you didn't use placeholders in the query.

Comment: Why did you do it the right way for `INSERT`, but not for `UPDATE`?

Comment: I'm a stupid man. I've just been messing about for the past 30minutes trying to fix it, just trying stuff. I'm led to believe preparedstatements are better security wise as well?

Comment: Yes, they prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Fabulous. Well thankyou so much for the advice and help. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed prepared statement (`query`) with an ordinary one (`update`), and that is the problem in your code - you did not escape your input, and MySQL treats unescaped text as column name.

That should work:

```
    update=c.prepareStatement ("UPDATE inventory set stockAmount =? WHERE productID =?");
    update.setInt(1, amount);
    update.setString(2, productID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't quote the product ID in the `UPDATE` query. But you should use a parametrized query, like you did for the `INSERT`.

```
        update=c.prepareStatement ("UPDATE inventory set stockAmount  ? WHERE productID = ?");
        update.setInt(1, amount);
        update.setString(2, productID);
        update.execute();
```

You should also use `query.setInt(4, amount);` since `amount` is an integer, not a string.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the help! 

It seems to be doing the job however it's always changing the stockAmount to the one figure i'm using. So i'm needing to figure out a way to perform addition and subtraction on it.

Comment: `set stockAmount = stockAmount + ?` to add to it.

Comment: `set stockAmount = stockAmount - ?` to subtract. That's probably more appropriate for an order.